# Load package into current namespace

Tags: tcl

How can I load the contents of a package into the current namespace instead of the global namespace?

Suppose I have the following package.tcl

```
package provide pgkTest 1.0

variable _value ""
proc get_value {} {
  variable _value
  return _value
}
```

The package is listed in pkgIndex.tcl and is found. Now in the main script in another folder I would like to do:

```
namespace eval myns1 {
   package require pgkTest 1.0
   package forget pgkTest 
}

namespace eval myns2 {
   package require pgkTest 1.0
   package forget pgkTest 
}
```

However, this does not seem to work because the package is loaded into the global namespace :: by default.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do won't work, because each package (as determined by its name) is loaded at most once into an interpreter. Instead, the package probably ought to provide a command that sets up a given namespace with the features you're after:

```
package provide pgkTest 1.0

namespace eval ::pgkTest {}
proc ::pgkTest::setup {{targetNamespace ""}} {
    # If caller doesn't give a namespace, get the caller's namespace
    if {$targetNamespace eq ""} {
        set targetNamespace [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]
    }
    namespace eval $targetNamespace {
        variable _value ""
        proc get_value {} {
          variable _value
          return _value
        } 
    }
}
```

Then you can do this to get the *effect* you want:

```
package require pgkTest 1.0

namespace eval myns1 {
    ::pgkTest::setup
}

namespace eval myns2 {
   ::pgkTest::setup
}
```

If you're really doing this sort of thing a lot, *consider switching to using an object system like TclOO, [incr Tcl], or XOTcl.* They're designed much more for tackling the problem of stamping out lots of copies of things that are all the same (or have minor variations).